# Game UI Programming

Tags: opengl, gui, ui-design

I'm looking for recommendation for resources for learning UI Game programming, i'm creating a simple game in C++ and OpenGL but it gonna be UI heavy and i wanna learn how to write a good UI system for it.

Comment: "How to get started" questions are off-topic here. If you can edit & re-frame your question to focus on a specific problem you're facing with your UI design, then it might be on-topic and attract suggestions for how to solve it.

Comment: How about making your game with an existing GUI framework, such as Qt or imgui? Then you'll have a done game, an insight on what a GUI framework might look like, and a list of first-hand usage issues which you'll be able to consider when designing your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations for learning resources are (unfortunately?) off topic on gamedev.stackexchange so I won't answer that part.

Learning UI game programming can and should be split into 2 parts, Design and Development.

---

To learn about Development, the best you can do is to look at multiple existing complete frameworks ([QT](https://www.qt.io/), [WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/introduction-to-wpf-in-vs), etc), and try to figure out what is the same and what is different, and try to guess **why**.

In addition, I strongly recommend you use an existing GUI framework for C++ and OpenGL - because these are the technologies you decided to use - then look for tutorials specific to that framework. Using an existing framework will allow you to skip many "minor" issues which become a lot bigger once you have to solve them on your own. A great example of these "minor" issues is UI resizing for different screen sizes and resolutions.

---

UI Design unfortunately is trickier, and here you indeed need some book recommendations (which are off topic here). Other than book recommendations, my advice is that you focus on rapid prototyping.

The fastest prototypes are created with pen and paper. For interactive prototypes some specialized applications exist, but I recommend instead of specialized applications you create interactive prototypes using the very GUI framework you're going to use to create your game. This is another reason to use an existing framework: when prototyping you don't want to be stopped by the need to implement major features.